# why certificate in the store is not listed out in the outlook for signing and encryption?

Tags: openssl, cryptography

If a certificate is imported in to the personal store from a .pfx file, it is being listed out for signing and encryption in the outlook.

Whereas if this .pfx file is imported using the function PFXImportCertStore(); and later added to the certificate store using the functions as

```
        //
        // Open the certificate store to add certificates to store
        //
        hUsrCertStore = CertOpenSystemStore(
            NULL,
            L"MY" );
        if ( ! hUsrCertStore )
        {
            hResult =  GetLastError( );
            __leave;
        } // if

        //
        // Add the created certificate into system certificate store
        //
        if ( ! CertAddCertificateContextToStore(
            hUsrCertStore,
            pUsrSignCertContext,
            CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING,
            0 ) )
        {
            hResult = GetLastError( );
            __leave;
        } // if
```

If it is added programmatically, it is not being listed out in the outlook.
What can be the reason of this behaviour of the pfx file?

Comment: Do you close the store after adding the certificate?

Comment: yes, close the store after adding the certificate and also tried without closing the store